# Can't see the top section with(file ,view ,tool etc) where I went wrong

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm setting up an android studio for **flutter**, however doesn't look proper. I also don't have any issue with running the flutter doctor command.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1st goto your directory/folder where you like to create a project. then open terminal and

1. `flutter create project_name`
2. `cd prokect_name`
3. `code .` it may open vscode or other editor that you have, else right click mouse  on `project_name` open with `andoridStudio`

you may also find `file> newProject >flutter`

Comment: the problem wasn't creating flutter app, however it's on andriod studio lay. I'm coming from macbook to windows ,so the layout looks different , plus it might seems I'm overlooking something.

Comment: one of the issues is that when opened the flutter project on Vscode, it doesn't come with gradle file.

Comment: did you build/run the app

Comment: Thank you so much ,I think you're right, I just ran flutter build and it added .